# The angle of the intersection of two graphs

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

I encounter some problems with understanding the explanation of the follwing problem:

> For which value of $\alpha$ does the graph of $f_\alpha(x)=e^{\alpha x}$ intersect the graph of $g(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$ orthogonally in the point $(0,1)$?

Normally, in this kind of problem, I would calculate both derivatives and equal them with the tangent of the angle, but $\tan(90^\circ)$ is not defined. In the explanation they are using $f'(0) \cdot g'(0) = -1$, but I don't understand how they obtained it. Is there a formula that I forgot?

[image: This is a screenshot with the problem and the explanation that the site gives]

Comment: Yes - the slopes of two perpendicular straight lines satisfy $m\cdot m' = -1$ - that's a basic result in plane analytic geometry.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: $tan(\alpha+ \beta)= \frac{tan(\alpha)+ tan(\beta)}{1- tan(\alpha)tan(\beta)}$ is a basic trig identity.  We cannot just let $\beta$ equal 90 degrees because, as you say, $tan(90)$ is not defined.  But we can divide numerator and denominator on the right by $cos(\beta)$ first to get $tan(\alpha}+ \beta)= \frac{\frac{tan(\alpha)}{tan(\beta)}+ 1}{\frac{1}{tan(\beta)}-  tan(\alpha)}$.

Comment: tan(α+β)=(tan(α)+tan(β))/(1−tan(α)tan(β)) is a basic trig identity. We cannot just let β equal 90 degrees because, as you say, tan(90) is not defined. But we can divide numerator and denominator on the right by cos(β) first to get tan(α+β)= ((tan(α)/tan(β)+ 1)/(1/tan(β)- tan(α)).  Now letting β go to 90 degrees, the fractions with tan(β) in the denominator got to 0 so that tan(α+ 90)= 1/(-tan(α)= -1/tan(α).